# Javascript trying to get the non repeating values from 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the non repeating values from the 2 inputs.
Ex: If I type some names in the first input: George, Michael, John and in 2nd input: John, Robert, Michael.
should return in the 3 input: George, Robert.

```
# const resultElement = document.getElementById('ResultField');
      const text1Element = document.getElementById('old');
      const text2Element = document.getElementById('new');

      function myFunction() {
        const x = text1Element.value;
        const y = text2Element.value;

        //split the textareas by newlines
        const xArr = x.split('\n');
        const yArr = y.split('\n');

        const result = xArr
          .map((line, index) => {
            return line + ' ' + yArr[index];
          }, '')
          .join('\n');

        const removeDuplicates = result.split(/\s/g).filter((word, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(word) !== i);

        resultElement.value = removeDuplicates;
      }
```

using this line I get the duplicates. ex: Michael, John
const removeDuplicates = result.split(/\s/g).filter((word, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(word) !== i);

if I change "!" to "=" I get the combine input. ex: George, Michael, John, Robert
const removeDuplicates = result.split(/\s/g).filter((word, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(word) === i);

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a count of the words in a concatenated list, then filter out any word that appeared more than once.

```js
const xArr = x.split('\n');
const yArr = y.split('\n');
const both = xArr.concat(yArr);

const counts = both.reduce((aggCounts, name) => {
  aggCounts[name] = (aggCounts[name] || 0) + 1;
  return aggCounts;
}, {});

resultElement.value = both.filter(name => counts[name] < 2).join('\n');
```

This has an O(n) runtime, with O(n) space.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the symmetric differences.

```
// ...

const xArr = x.split('\n');
const yArr = y.split('\n');

const diff = xArr.filter(x => !yArr.includes(x)).concat(yArr.filter(y => !xArr.includes(y)));

resultElement.value = diff.join('\n')
```

Comment: it concats the two together, but I need only to return the non repeating values from both of them for ex xArr=[ a, b , c] yArr=[a, c, d] the  result=[b, d]. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**You can use** `concat()` , `includes()` and `filter()` **together and create a solution like below:**

```
var uniqueNames = names1.filter(name => !names2.includes(name)).concat(names2.filter(name => !names1.includes(name)));
```

**Refer the code below :**

```js
function findCommonNames() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value="George, Michael, John";
        var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value="John, Robert, Michael";


        var names1 = input1.split(',').map(name => name.trim());
        var names2 = input2.split(',').map(name => name.trim());


        var uniqueNames = names1.filter(name => !names2.includes(name)).concat(names2.filter(name => !names1.includes(name)));

 
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Unique Names: ' + uniqueNames.join(', ');
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Common Names Finder</h1>
    
    <label for="input1">Enter names (comma-separated)1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="George, Michael, John">
     <br>

    <label for="input2">Enter names (comma-separated)2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="John, Robert, Michael">
    <br>
    <button onclick="findCommonNames()">Find Common Names</button>

    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```